# Reading defined bytes that i loaded into a different segment [NASM, real mode]

Tags: assembly, return, nasm, real-mode, memory-segmentation

I loaded this code off of the disk at 0x1000:0x0000

Here is the memory address of `wtf` being pushed onto the stack in segment 0x1000, then returning to segment 0:

```
mov ax, wtf
push ax
push ds

mov ax, 0
push ax
mov ax, word [ds:0x1000]
push ax
retf ;going back to segment 0

wtf db 'hi', 0
```

and here is me trying to access the memory address from segment 0

```
mov ax, 0x1000
mov ds, ax

mov ah, 0x0e
mov al, byte [ds:0x004e]
int 0x10
```

im using 0x004e because that is the value that got pushed onto the stack with `push wtf`.
However, int 0x10 outputs null and still moves the cursor. The expected output would be 'h'...
What is going on here?

Comment: It is really unclear what you are doing here. This smells like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What is it you are really trying to achieve>

Comment: @MichaelPetch i'm trying to access a reference to intialized data (wtf db). The reference exists, but the data is null at runtime.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to identify a culprit. If 0x1000:0x004e is that actual location of `wtf` then the code in the second snippet should work and print `h`. The fact that it prints something else indicated either that memory address isn't where `wtf` is located or possibly whatever code you jumped to in segment 0 is not where you expected to go. For example from this code I can't tell if `mov ax, word [ds:0x1000]` actually moves the correct return address to the stack to initiate the far return (effectively turns things into a FAR JMP)

Comment: Not related to your problem. You seem to be trying jump to code in another segment and passing the FAR address of a string on the stack. If you had pushed ax and ds  in reverse order  (`push ds` `push ax` instead of `push ax` `push ds`) you could have later on (after the `retf`) loaded the FAR address from the stack into DS:BX with something like `mov bp, sp` `lds bx, [bp]` and then done `mov ah, 0x0e` `mov al, byte [bx]` `int 0x10`